# How do we know the expected value of Y given X? (population regression function)

Tags: regression

Why does $E(Y|X)=B_0+B_1X$ give exactly the conditional expectation of $Y$ for a given $X$ value? I don't understand how we can know the average value of $Y$ for a given $X$ value. In my drawing I circled an obervation (x). How do we know now, given only this oberservation, that the average of $Y$ given $X$ is on the line? Wouldn't we we need more obervations for this given $X$ value to conclude where the average is? I'm quite confused, I hope you understand what I mean.

[image]

Comment: This equation is a *model*; it does not say anything about the *data.*

Comment: Then why call the predicted values the “mean of y?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we know that $Y_i=E(Y_i|X_i)+e_i$ where $E(e_i|X_i)=0$ by conditional expectation function decomposition. Basicaly if we have some outcome $Y$, we can split it into the expectation and an error term that conditional on X has zero mean.

Now suppose we think there is a linear relationship between Y and X:

$Y_i=B_0+B_1X+e_i$

Then from the above we have: $ E(Y_i|X_i)=B_0+B_1X$ and we say that the conditional expectation function (the LHS) is a linear predictor in this case.

This is a model that predicts where the expected value is. But we never actually observe that so we create estimates and get sample averages using data.

Comment: But how can the predicted y on the regression line be called the “mean of y” when we only have one data point for each value of x? I think this is where the OP is getting confused, and me too.

Comment: @user3138766 If we think the regression line represents the conditional expectation function (Y given X), then the predicted y is just the estimate of that function at that point. Whether or not it is a good estimate for the conditional mean depends on how much data we have. I'm not sure if this answers your question.